# MySql query to UPDATE duplicate rows is very slow. Suggestions need to speed up

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-update

I have table `promotional` with columns (`promoid`,`mobile`,`message_sent_status`, and 15 more...).
This table have approx 10 Thousands rows. I want to update a column's value (`mobile`)  to blank (`empty string`) which has duplicate entries except the first occurrence.

```
UPDATE promotional
SET mobile='', message_sent_status='BLANK'
WHERE mobile!='' and promo_id not in
                 (
                   SELECT min(promo_id)
                   FROM (SELECT * FROM promotional) as temp
                   GROUP BY mobile
                 );
```

This query is working fine but taking a lot of time (approx 1 min) even if there is no duplicate entry found.

But when I change the line

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM promotional) as temp

// with only required column
FROM (SELECT promo_id, mobile,messsage_sent_status, FROM promotional) as temp
```

It takes approx 40 seconds.

I want to know that if there is any way to speed up the query or the time taken by the query is acceptable.

Comment: Try to use the multi table update version instead of the subquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SQL is not correct to update, because your question is to keep each min promoid per each mobile

Not sure your table keys, it will speed up if you have an index key on mobile:

```
alter table promotional add key (mobile)
```

Then run this:

```
UPDATE promotional AS a
JOIN   promotional AS b
ON  a.mobile = b.mobile
AND a.promoid < b.promoid
AND a.mobile != ''
SET b.message_sent_status = ''
```

My Testing table has 33840 rows and above SQL takes .5 seconds

[image]

And I did another test, 163,840 rows takes 16.4 secends pretty quick:

[image]

Comment: The execution for 10,000 rows time is just 15 sec when running the query without adding index. After adding index the execution time is just .3 sec.
`Index` is really powerful.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Get rid if the innermost query:

```
SELECT MIN(promo_id)
    FROM promotional
    GROUP BY mobile
```

(2) Try to use amulti-table `UPDATE`.  But that will probably fail because of referencing the same table twice.

So...

(3) Use a temp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t
        ( PRIMARY KEY(promo_id) )   -- To help with LEFT JOIN, below
    SELECT MIN(promo_id) AS promo_id
        FROM promotional
        GROUP BY mobile;
# do SELECT * FROM t; to see if it looks good
UPDATE promotional
    LEFT JOIN t USING(promo_id) 
    SET mobile = '', message_sent_status = 'BLANK'
    WHERE mobile != ''
      AND t.promo_id IS NULL;   -- replaces "NOT IN"
```

(4) Consider moving `mobile` into another table so you don't have to do this again.  Seems like `SELECT mobile, MIN(promo_id) FROM promotional GROUP BY mobile;` would give you such a table.

Comment: Do I need to create Temporary table every time ?

Comment: If this is are recurring task, then step back some distance and rethink the design.  You should not need to do such a costly task repeatedly.  Since I don't know what the _real_ goal is, I am at a loss of how to help you redesign the system.  Perhaps based on my '(4)'?

Comment: line 2 -- Which is line 2?  (I made a change, don't know if it is related.)

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY(promo_id)` (fixed).  I hope there are no more dumb typos.